# Sum of a column from Jquery table

Tags: jquery

I am using following template for data tables and wanted to have sum of the column at the end for specific column.

http://almsaeedstudio.com/AdminLTE/pages/tables/data.html

I am using Data Table With Full Features column.

```
<table>
<tr>.....</tr>
    <tr class="sum">
        <th>Total</th>
        <td class="sum">#</td>
    </tr>
</table>


function sumOfColumns(table, columnIndex) {
    var tot = 0;
    table.find("tr").children("td:nth-child(" + columnIndex + ")")
    .each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass("sum") && $this.html() != "") {
            tot += parseInt($this.html());
        }
    });
    return tot;
}

function do_sums() {
    $("tr.sum").each(function(i, tr) {
        $tr = $(tr);
        $tr.children().each(function(i, td) {
            $td = $(td);
            var table = $td.parent().parent().parent();
            if ($td.hasClass("sum")) {
                $td.html(sumOfColumns(table, i+1));
            }
        })
    });
}
```

I am not getting any results. Can you please help?

Comment: Are you using jquery data tables plugin..? if so, tag it in question. And provide a demo such as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) if possible...

Comment: Although not as efficient as it could be, the code seems like it should work. Create a simple demo in jsfiddle.net